# $location.path(/some/path) weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

FYI Im still in the learning process for AngularJS..
So, i have made this simple login application and if the login is succesful the view should change by loading an html-file (the html-file is just a short sentence greeting the user:) ).

However, it seems like it changes the view two times instead of one because if i press the back button in my browser, the correct page is loaded. I will explain it in more depth below :)

so, my start URL is this: **localhost:8888/Angular/exercise/indexLogin.html**.
When i successfully log in, the url should change to: **localhost:8888/Angular/exercise/indexLogin.html/dashboard** but instead it changes to this: **localhost:8888/?username=admin&password=admin**

[Picture of my code where I change the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0QFW.png)

Index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AngularJS learning</title>        
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="loginController.js"></script>


</head>

<body ng-app="loginApp">

    <div ng-view>

    </div>

</body>

<script>

</script>

</html>
```

Login.html (the login screen):

```
<div ng-controller="loginController">
<form action="/" id="myLogin">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username"><br>     Password: <input type="password" name="password"       id="password" ng-model="password">
<button ng-click="submitLogin()">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
```

dashboard.html

```
<div ng-controller="loginController">
Du er logget ind!
</div>
```

I hope you can understand my question - if not, feel free to ask :)

//Jacob

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, post the code as text.

Comment: Can you please provide the html code also?

Comment: Remove the / before dashboard and try. or try #/dashboard.

Comment: html code is now posted :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. In **login.html** i found out that "action='/'" in  the  'form' tag redirected my view to the root of my server. So my routing actually worked but right after execution it got redirected to path '/'.